# jquery keydown function disable running when keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I've created a div with an jquery animation that looks like this:

```
$("body").keydown(function (Taste) {

var figPosNow = $("#figur").css("top");
var figPosNowInt = parseInt(figPosNow);
var changePos = 0;

if (Taste.keyCode == 38) {

    changePos -= 100;
    Taste.preventDefault();

}

var newFigPos = (figPosNowInt + changePos) + "px";

$("#figur").animate({top: newFigPos}, 200).animate({top: figPosNow}, 200);
});
```

The problem is that when you hold down the button that the function keep adding up and they still all run even when you release the button.

Is is possible to declare that a animation should never run when the key is held down, but only when it's pressed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead; or

```js
var i = 1;

$("body").keyup(function (Taste) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(i + " key.");
    i++;
});
```

```css
#figur{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: indigo;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="figur"></div>

</body>
```

If you realy need it on [.keydown()](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/), you can use flag (with [.keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) triggering and [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) if you necessary, to return to the original value)

```js
var i = 1, allow = true;

$("body").keydown(function(Taste){
    if(allow){
      console.clear();
      console.log(i + " key.");
      i++;
      allow = false;
    }
});

$("body").keyup(function(e){
    allow = true;
});

$("body").focus(function(e){
    allow = true;
});
```

```css
#figur{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: indigo;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="figur"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the event to happen on `keyup` or `keypress` or you'll need to keep a flag for the key being down, only run the code when the key isn't down, and reset the flag on `keyup`.

```
var keyDown = false;

$("body").keydown(function (Taste) {
    if (Taste.keyCode == 38) {
      keyDown = true;
      Taste.preventDefault();

      var figPosNow = $("#figur").css("top");
      var figPosNowInt = parseInt(figPosNow);
      var changePos = -100;
      var newFigPos = (figPosNowInt + changePos) + "px";

      $("#figur").animate({top: newFigPos}, 200).animate({top: figPosNow}, 200);
    }
  }
});

$("body").keyup(function (Taste) {
  if (Taste.keyCode == 38) {
    keyDown = false;
  }
});
```